# Line Break in Font Rendering

Tags: java, line, break

So I just created a Font sprite sheet for my Java Game, and have implemented this method into a class to draw text using that sprite sheet.

```
public static void renderText(Graphics2D g, String message, int x, int y, int size) {

    message = message.toUpperCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        char c = message.charAt(i);
        if(c == 47) c = 36; // slash
        if(c == 58) c = 37; // colon
        if(c == 32) c = 38; // space
        if(c == 46) c = 40; // period
        if(c == 95) c = 39; // underscore
        if(c == 33) c = 41; // exclamation point
        if(c == 63) c = 42; // question mark
        if(c == 39) c = 43; // apostrophe
        if(c >= 65 && c <= 90) c -= 65; // letters
        if(c >= 48 && c <= 57) c -= 22; // numbers
        int row = c / font[0].length; // font is a 2D Array of BufferedImages from the sprite sheet 
        int col = c % font[0].length;
        g.drawImage(font[row][col], x + size * i, y, size, size, null);
    }

}
```

This all works fine, but the strings it renders are usually longer than the window. I tried using `String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator")`, but that gives me an error because when it tries to render that `newline` string, it doesn't know what character to use.

How could I test if the string is longer than the window and then implement some sort of line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply call `font[row][col].getTileWidth()` to get the pixel width of each sprite and ensure that the sum <= width of the panel.

Also, what's happening here?

```
if(c == 95) c = 39; // underscore
...
if(c == 39) c = 43; // apostrophe
```

Is that really the intent?

Comment: Thank you! And yeah, I knew there was a problem with that, thanks for pointing that out. I'll swap the two around. :)

Comment: I got the line break to work, but how could I make it so it doesn't break the line half-way through a word?

Comment: Hmmm...  You could search for and react to whitespace; otherwise, you'll end up having to keep a Set of all possible words that could show up (for a game, this might not be totally outrageous) and basing the code flow on that.  In any case, for each new word, just check total pixel width against remaining width in the panel and break early as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you need to be rolling your own renderer. Using the system font renderer has a number of advantages, including the fact that it is able to take advantage of advanced caching and all sorts of other things that your graphics system is just begging to do if you will just let it. (Not to mention that it also actually works.)

If you want to display the text in a custom font face, then use a custom font face. A quick google turns up all sorts of results for  how to [create a font from images](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+font+from+images), [create a custom font](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+custom+font), or use an [icon font generator](http://www.google.com/search?q=icon+font+generator). Once you have the font, add it as a resource to your project, similar to how you would add images, and use that.

Another related option is to define it as a new subclass of [`java.awt.Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

Comment: I have tried a lot of these custom font generators, and none have worked how I want them to. My renderer works just fine, I just need to know how to add a couple more things. Thank you. :)

Comment: @sparklyllama clearly, you didn't try hard enough. You probably will need to __download and install__ a font creation package in order use your existing image tiles. Alternately, you could try a tool like FontStruct, which allows you to create a font directly online, although it doesn't let you import images.